# What is the fastest way to find the value of x for the given statement ?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, polynomial-math, equation-solving

All I know is that a single integer will surely accept it.

The equation is like :
**Ax^5  +  Bx^3  +  Cx^2 = D**

I tried to brute force value of x , but was getting TLE , can I use an  optimised binary search as I know *only one root will be real*?

Comment: You have to know much more about A, B, C, and D in order to say "one root will be real".  What is "TLE"?  It seems like you're getting this problem from somewhere, but are leaving out a lot of details.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am guessing TLE stands for Time Limit Expired.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to search for Newton-Raphson's method which is known to quickly converge to solution with just a few iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You're just asking to find the zeros of a function when you've been guaranteed that there's no more than one zero. To put it concretely, let's assume you have the following equation:

```
-15x^5 + 12x^3 - 203x^2 = -2.193113e+12
```

You could use the root-finding function from your favorite statistical software package to find the root. For instance, here's how you would do it with `uniroot` in R:

```
uniroot(function(x) -15*x^5 + 12*x^3 - 203*x^2 + 2.193113e+12, c(-1000, 1000))$root
# [1] 171
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try typing this into Wolfram Alpha.

```
Solve[3x^5+4 x^3+5x^2==148,x]
```

[image]